# Shiny issue related to withMathJax and the evaluation order

Tags: r, shiny, mathjax

Yesterday, I did my first attempt at creating a shiny app. I have come this far but some things I don't quite understand yet so here is the app:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

### Ui

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Distributions"),
   sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(
       selectInput("dist", "Distribution",
                    c("Normal distribution"       = "norm",
                      "t-distribution"            = "t",
                      "Poisson distribution"      = "pois"
                  )
                  ),

       uiOutput("ui")
       ),
     mainPanel(
       plotOutput("plot")
       )
      )
     )
     )


### Server

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
       output$ui <- renderUI({
         switch(input$dist,
                "norm" = withMathJax(wellPanel(numericInput("norm_mu", "Mean: \\(\\mu\\)", value = 0),
                                               numericInput("norm_sd", "Standard deviation: \\(\\sigma\\)", value = 1, min = 0))),
                "t"    = numericInput("t_df", "Degrees of freedom:", value = 1, min = 1),
                "pois" = withMathJax(numericInput("pois_lambda", "Parameter: \\(\\lambda\\)",
                                                  value = 1))
                )
         })

       output$plot <- renderPlot({
          dist_range <-  switch(input$dist,
                                "norm" = c(-10, 10),
                                "t"    = c(-10, 10),
                                "pois" = seq(0, 20, by = 1))
          a <- ggplot(data.frame(x = dist_range), aes(x = x))
          a <- a + switch(input$dist,
                           "norm" = stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = input$norm_mu, sd = input$norm_sd)),
                           "t"    = stat_function(fun = dt, args = list(df = input$t_df)),
                "pois"  = geom_bar(aes(y = dpois(x, lambda = input$pois_lambda)), stat = "identity")
                          )
          a
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Now my questions are:

1. When I run the app for the first time, I get no plot in the main panel but two errors in my console:

   ```
   Error in (function (x, mean = 0, sd = 1, log = FALSE)  : 
   Non-numeric argument for mathematical function

   Error in exists(name, envir = env, mode = mode) : 
   argument "env" is missing, with no default
   ```

   I figured out, that `withMathJax` is causing these errors but two things  puzzle me anyway.

   a.  When I remove `withMathJax`, the plot appears but I still get those errors. Why is that?
   b.  If I dont remove `withMathJax`, run the app and then chose another distribution, I get a plot, however the errors are still there. If I go back to the normal distribution again, the plot appears (along with errors). If I choose the t-distribution again, everything works perfectly without any errors. Why is that ?

Note: I guess it has something to do with what gets evaluated when and how. If so, could someone 1.) clarify that for me or at least point to some good documentation and 2.) explain how to avoid this behaviour.

2. Choosing the Poisson distribution results in an error:

   ```
   Error in dpois(x, lambda = input$pois_lambda) : object 'input' not found
   ```

   Why can't `input$pois_lambda` be accessed here? What is different to the `stat_function(...)` part used for the normal and the t-distribution, where accessing doesn't seem to be a problem?

Help is much appreciated! Thanks